# How to trigger a setInterval function on a user click?

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm trying to write a JS timer that will be triggered by a user click on the button with id="start".

I've got the timer itself working correctly, but when I try to add code to initiate the timer on the button click (id="start") I break it and am not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var count = 0;

        $('#start').click(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                count++;
                $('#timer').html(count + ' tacos seconds');
            },1000);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Ughhh. Just realized I forgot the '$' at the start. Editing now.

Comment: This will start a new interval timer on a click. What exactly is desired/wrong? However, it is likely that multiple timers should not be allowed to stack...

Comment: Is the problem that your interval function is not running or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: How can I remove this question? Since it turned out to be a non-question?

Comment: @john k Actions should be under the "tags". Choose ... delete :)

Comment: @pst I must be missing something. I only see link, edit and flag

Comment: @john k Might be a rep. thing then :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start').click((function(container) {
        var interval;
        return function() {
            if(interval) clearInterval(interval);

            var count = 0;

            interval = setInterval(function() {
                count++;
                $(container).html(count + ' tacos seconds');
            }, 1000);
        };
    })("#timer"));
});
```

Comment: How will this address the (unspecified) problem? :-) (Not that I am opposed to reducing the scope of `count`, if appropriate. In this case the double-binding just makes the code more complicated to understand).

Comment: Updated to prevent multiple timers and scoped the count better.

Comment: As for making things more complicated, if a person is trying to use callbacks and anon functions and asynchronous operations are too confusing they need to find a new hobby/job.

Comment: And one more update. I really future proofed the shit out of it.

Comment: Thanks! I actually was trying to delete this question originally because I realized I'd just missed a "$" that was breaking the whole thing but this bit you submitted helps me fix the count issue as well. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Ryan Olds This code is complicated because the double-binding is *hidden*. On a cursory glance it appears that the `return` (and `container`) is for the event callback -- when it is not. Changing the code structure can make the intent more clear. The issue isn't the (useless in this case) double-binding, but *how it makes the code harder to follow based on how the code is written*. Too-clever is too-clever. In this case the reader has to scan to the very end where the outer function is applied to "get it". (I might settle on a named nested function which created the closure, if required.)

Comment: Hidden? It's pretty obvious what's going on. Much less can go wrong wrong with interval properly scoped like it is in my example. While not optimal my sample can also be multiple times in that block without conflicting - the optimal version is my 2nd answer.

Comment: **In this case the reader has to scan to the very end where the outer function is applied to "get it".** That's the core of the argument: hidden.

Comment: I don't know about you, but if I'm asking a question and someone provides me some code I'm going to read all of it. How else am I'm going to "get it"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var myInterval = null;
  $('#start').click(function(){
      myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        count++;
        $('#timer').html(count + ' tacos seconds');
      },1000);
  });
```

});

When setting your setInterval in the scope of the click handler, try assigning it to a variable to hold the interval declared up a level.  This has typically always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactily what your objective is, but maybe you'd want to try something like this:

```
var startInterveal;
var timerStarted = false;
var count =0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start').click(function () {
        if (!timerStarted) {
            timerStarted = true;
            count =0;
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            startInterveal = setInterval('tick();', 1000);
        }
    });
});

function tick() {
    count++;
    $('#timer').html(count + ' tacos seconds');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2nd answer if you really want to go nuts and have something resuable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start').click(overboard("#timer"));
    $('#start2').click(overboard("#timer2"));
});

function overboard(container) {
    var interval;
    return function() {
        if (interval) clearInterval(interval);

        var count = 0;

        interval = setInterval(function() {
            count++;
            $(container).html(count + ' tacos seconds');
        }, 1000);
    };
}
```