# SetInterval has to be triggered whenever the time is getting changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, date, react-hooks

Am using setInterval for updating the time, for that i have set 60000s as interval. whenever i load the page i will get the time and time is getting updated after 1 minute from when i have refreshed the page but not with respective to the time. Hence there is some delay in updating the time.

```
   const UpdateTime= (props) => {
    let date = new Date();
    const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState({
        curTime: date.toLocaleDateString(),
        timeStr: date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, " "),
        curDay: date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            let date = new Date();
            setDateTime({
                curTime: date.toLocaleDateString(),
                timeStr: date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, " "),
                curDay: date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })
            });
        },
            60000
        );
        return () => { clearInterval(interval) }
    }, [])
}
```

after loading the page, whenever the date.getSeconds() is reaching 00 from there i have to trigger the setinterval function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to go in this way, I guess there's no other solution than this:
Because you can't 'trigger' intervals just simulating it ([How to trigger a setInterval function on a user click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076746/how-to-trigger-a-setinterval-function-on-a-user-click)), you can use function which will be called by the interval. Then you can call that function when the `date.getSeconds()` reach 00. However for this you will need a second interval which triggered every second until it reach the 00 and than you can clear it. After you called it and the second is 00 you set the interval for 60 seconds.
It's necessary to reset the 60s interval or it will be inaccurate again.

Answer (score 0):

i have used setTimeOut to call the interval function whenever date.getSeconds() becomes 0 for the first time. But the problem what i am facing is i couldn't able to clear the interval. I am getting more "inside timeout and inside interval" in the console its not clearing the previous log, i am expecting timeout to be one and whenever the setInterval runs then i have to get the "inside interval" in the console

```
const DateTime = (props) => {
let date = new Date();
let initialDiff = (date.getSeconds() == 0) ? 0 : (59 - date.getSeconds());
setTimeout(() => {
    triggerDateUpdate()
    console.log("inside timeout")

}, initialDiff * 1000);
const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState({
    curTime: date.toLocaleDateString(),
    timeStr: date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, " "),
    curDay: date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })
});
const interval = () => {
    console.log("inside interval")
    let date = new Date();
    setDateTime({
        curTime: date.toLocaleDateString(),
        timeStr: date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, " "),
        curDay: date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })
    });
}
let triggerDateUpdate = () => {
    interval();
    setInterval(() => {
        interval();
    }, 60000)
}
```